# Can I delete these mystery desktop files which have appeared in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, extension

I just enabled Desktop Icons on Ubuntu 20.04 through Extensions and the following four mystery icons (.desktop files) appeared, with the respective contents:

- `trash-can.desktop`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=pcmanfm-qt trash:///
  Icon=user-trash-full
  Name=Trash (73 items)
  ```
- `network.desktop`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=pcmanfm-qt network:///
  Icon=folder-network
  Name=Network
  ```
- `user-home.desktop`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=pcmanfm-qt /home/[user]
  Icon=user-home
  Name=[user]
  ```
- `computer.desktop`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=pcmanfm-qt computer:///
  Icon=computer
  Name=Computer
  ```

Can I delete these?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that these icons are created by PCManFM-Qt. If you are using it as your main file manager, you should disable the Desktop Icons extension and let PCManFM-Qt handle the desktop by running it as `pcmanfm-qt --desktop` (see [PCManFM-Qt's Usage section](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt#usage)).

If you have used PCManFM-Qt just to try it and you have uninstalled it, you can safely delete the icons and use Desktop Icons as your desktop manager.